# Oracle invalid use of type name or subtype name

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What is wrong with the this block am using? please help to solve this.
Only one row will be selected based on the where clause.

**Table clazzes**

```
Name Type          Nullable Default Comments 
---- ------------- -------- ------- -------- 
ID   NUMBER(10)                              
NAME VARCHAR2(100) Y
```

**PL/SQL Block :**

```
declare
type clazzes_row_type is record
(clazz_rownum number,
 clazz_id clazzes.id%type,
 clazz_name clazzes.name%type);
begin
clazzes_row_type.clazz_rownum :=111;
select id,name into clazzes_row_type.clazz_id,clazzes_row_type.clazz_name
from clazzes where name ='leo1';
dbms_output.put_line(clazzes_row_type.clazz_id);
dbms_output.put_line(clazzes_row_type.clazz_rownum);
dbms_output.put_line(clazzes_row_type.clazz_name);
end;
```

**Exception :**

```
ORA-06550: line 8, column 1:
PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
ORA-06550: line 8, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 9, column 21:
PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
ORA-06550: line 9, column 75:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 9, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 11, column 22:
PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
ORA-06550: line 11, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 12, column 22:
PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
ORA-06550: line 12, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 13, column 22:
PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
ORA-06550: line 13, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should declare a variable with the specified type. And instantiate your variable with a constructor:

```
declare
type clazzes_row_type is record
(clazz_rownum number,
 clazz_id clazzes.id%type,
 clazz_name clazzes.name%type);

myvariable clazzes_row_type;

begin
  myvariable := clazzes_row_type(111, null, null);
```

or with your select:

```
begin
  select 111,id,name into myvariable from clazzes where name ='leo1';
```

Comment: Thank you it was useful, halfcooked reading made me to do this.